# Amazon EKS (NFS) to Kubernetes pod. Can't mount volume

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm working on attaching Amazon EKS (NFS) to Kubernetes pod using terraform.

Everything runs without an error and is created:

- Pod victoriametrics
- Storage Classes
- Persistent Volumes
- Persistent Volume Claims

However, the volume `victoriametrics-data` doesn't attach to the pod. Anyway, I can't see one in the pod's shell.
Could someone be so kind to help me understand where I'm wrong, please?

I have cut some unimportant code for the question to get code shorted.

```golang
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "victoriametrics" {
...
      spec {
        container {
          image = var.image
          name  = var.name
          ...
          volume_mount {
              mount_path        = "/data"
              mount_propagation = "None"
              name              = "victoriametrics-data"
              read_only         = false
            }
        }

        volume {
            name = "victoriametrics-data"
        }

      }
    }
...

}
```

```golang
resource "kubernetes_csi_driver" "efs" {
  metadata {
    name = "${local.cluster_name}-${local.namespace}"
    annotations = {
      name = "For store data of ${local.namespace}."
    }
  }
  spec {
    attach_required        = true
    pod_info_on_mount      = true
    volume_lifecycle_modes = ["Persistent"]
  }
}
```

```golang
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "efs" {
  metadata {
    name = "efs-sc"
  }
  storage_provisioner = kubernetes_csi_driver.efs.id
  reclaim_policy      = "Retain"
  mount_options       = ["file_mode=0700", "dir_mode=0777", "mfsymlinks", "uid=1000", "gid=1000", "nobrl", "cache=none"]
}
```

```golang
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume" "victoriametrics" {
  metadata {
    name = "${local.cluster_name}-${local.namespace}"
  }
  spec {
    storage_class_name               = "efs-sc"
    persistent_volume_reclaim_policy = "Retain"
    volume_mode                      = "Filesystem"
    access_modes                     = ["ReadWriteMany"]
    capacity = {
      storage = var.size_of_persistent_volume_claim
    }
    persistent_volume_source {
      nfs {
        path   = "/"
        server = local.eks_iput_target
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```golang
resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "victoriametrics" {
  metadata {
    name      = local.name_persistent_volume_claim
    namespace = local.namespace
  }
  spec {
    access_modes       = ["ReadWriteMany"]
    storage_class_name = "efs-sc"
    resources {
      requests = {
        storage = var.size_of_persistent_volume_claim
      }
    }
    volume_name = kubernetes_persistent_volume.victoriametrics.metadata.0.name
  }
}
```

```yaml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: victoriametrics
  namespace: victoriametrics
  labels:
    k8s-app: victoriametrics
    purpose: victoriametrics
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
    name: >-
      VictoriaMetrics - The High Performance Open Source Time Series Database &
      Monitoring Solution.
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: victoriametrics
      purpose: victoriametrics
  template:
    metadata:
      name: victoriametrics
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: victoriametrics
        purpose: victoriametrics
      annotations:
        name: >-
          VictoriaMetrics - The High Performance Open Source Time Series
          Database & Monitoring Solution.
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: victoriametrics
          image: 714154805721.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/victoriametrics:v1.68.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8428
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 2003
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 2003
              protocol: UDP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: victoriametrics-data
            - mountPath: /var/log
              name: varlog
          env:
            - name: Name
              value: victoriametrics
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 1Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 1Gi
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      volumes:
      - name: victoriametrics-data
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: varlog
        emptyDir: {}    
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      automountServiceAccountToken: true
      shareProcessNamespace: false
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      tolerations:
        - key: k8s-app
          operator: Equal
          value: victoriametrics
          effect: NoSchedule
      enableServiceLinks: true
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  minReadySeconds: 15
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the persistent volume claim that you have created instead of `emptyDir` in your deployment:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: victoriametrics
...
  volumes:
  - name: victoriametrics-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: <value of local.name_persistent_volume_claim>
```

Comment: Thank you gohm'c!

Now I can attach NFS volume.

However, in spite 21Gi being set in claimed volume, the pod has 8E (full possible size of EFS).

May you be so kind to help me with this question, please?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917416/aws-eks-efs-mounted-volume-in-spite-21gi-in-claimed-volume-the-pod-has-8e-full