# AWS EKS EFS mounted volume. In spite 21Gi in claimed volume the pod has 8E (full possible size of EFS)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes

In spite 21Gi being set in claimed volume, the pod has 8E (full possible size of EFS)

Is it OK and storage size is limited. Or did I make a mistake in configuration and there needs to change, or something other?

I will be appreciated for your help.

**Volume:**

```
NAME                                    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                  
monitoring-eks-falcon-victoriametrics   21Gi       RWX            Retain           Bound    victoriametrics/victoriametrics-data
```

**Pod:**

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
fs-efs.us-....s.com:/     8.0E         0      8.0E   0% /data
```

**Persistent Volumes**

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: monitoring-eks-falcon-victoriametrics
  uid: f43e12d0-77ab-4530-8c9e-cfbd3c641467
  resourceVersion: '28847'
  labels:
    Name: victoriametrics
    purpose: victoriametrics
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: 'yes'
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 21Gi
  nfs:
    server: fs-.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    path: /
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  claimRef:
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    namespace: victoriametrics
    name: victoriametrics-data
    uid: 8972e897-4e16-a64f-4afd8f90fa89
    apiVersion: v1
    resourceVersion: '28842'
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

**Persistent Volume Claims**

```yaml
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: victoriametrics-data
  namespace: victoriametrics
  uid: 8972e897-4e16-a64f-4afd8f90fa89
  resourceVersion: '28849'
  labels:
    Name: victoriametrics
    purpose: victoriametrics
  annotations:
    Description: Volume for Victoriametrics DB
    pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: 'yes'
  finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: victoriametrics
      purpose: victoriametrics
    matchExpressions:
      - key: k8s-app
        operator: In
        values:
          - victoriametrics
  resources:
    limits:
      storage: 21Gi
    requests:
      storage: 21Gi
  volumeName: monitoring-eks-falcon-victoriametrics
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 21Gi
```

**Pod deployment**

```yaml
kind: Deployment
...
spec:
...
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: victoriametrics-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: victoriametrics-data
      containers:
        - name: victoriametrics
...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: victoriametrics-data
              mountPath: /data
              mountPropagation: None
...
```

Comment: See [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1000737/why-does-df-say-my-efs-disk-has-a-capacity-of-8-exabytes): it is just a quirk of the capacity reporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number "8E" serves as an indicator, it is not a real quota. AWS EFS does not support quota (eg. [FATTR4_QUOTA_AVAIL_HARD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/limits.html#nfs4-unsupported-features)). It generally means you have "unlimited" space on this mount. There's nothing wrong with your spec; the number specified in the PVC's `resources.requests.storage` is used to match PV's `capacity.storage`. It doesn't mean you can only write 21GB on the EFS mount.